# `[[self tableView] reloadData]` changes the NSMutableArray count

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray, uitableview, multiple-instances

I have an app that uses a UITablewView and in that TableView there is an NSMutableArray that holds the data to be displayed in the TabelView.
The problem is in my TableView Controller I use:

```
[[self tableView] reloadData]
```

To reload the TableView data and it works fine for a couple of times but doesn't work on the 3rd time and instead it changes the array count in a weird way.

Now I read [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233085/nsmutablearray-becoming-nil-after-reloaddata) question here and most likely I have 2 instances of the TableView or the TableViewController but I can't figure out how to troubleshoot this? How to detect if there are 2 instances of the object and fix that?

EDIT: Here is a pic how my navigation goes [image]

So the 1st round of going from ScrollView to TableView things show up correctly. Then I go to UIView and back to TableView and it's working fine. So I go back all the way to ScrollView and back again to TableView and it's good.

But when I go to the UIView for this time then back to TableView this problem happens. TableView doesn't display the changes. So I put a breakpoint just before `[[self tableView] reloadData]` and found out that the array `_displayedObjetcs` gets its count changed. -1 actually. see the following screen shots b4 and after I step over the `reloadData` [image: just before reloadData] 
and then

[image: just after reloadData]

Comment: to get a clue, use immutable copy of the array to feed the table view.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, I did that and it still changes the count after [[self tableView] reloadData] which i guess confirms the doubt that the TableView is reloading from another instance. But still how do I debug that?

Answer (score 1):

My immediate thought is that your array is not being retained properly, by your application. Your "weird" count is probably a number like 234791..., which is highly indicative of an array that has been released incorrectly. Therefore, I would check how your are retaining and releasing this array.

However, without more posted code, it is impossible to help you further.

Comment: I don't think that's why because the count number is only decremented by 1 which I guess is the array b4 it changes the 2nd time. I edited my question to make it more clear. Thanks again.